# How can I use a Module anonymously as the function for /@?

Tags: functions

I've looked for a similar question but the one that came up first has no answer, so please bear with me as I am a complete newbie to Mathematica.

My ultimate goal is to generate custom ticks for a plot. The X axis is in minutes (not actual units, just an integer) and represents overnight times from, for example, 10pm to 3am the next day.

I've written a short function in the form of a module to convert a 'minute' value into a string "hh:mm". This works fine.

```
f[x_] :=
 Module[{q, r},
  {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[x, 60];
  q = Mod[q, 24];
  q = IntegerString[q, 10, 2];
  r = IntegerString[r, 10, 2];
  StringJoin[q, ":", r]
  ]

myTicks[min_, max_] := f /@ FindDivisions[{min, max, 60}, 5]

myTicks[22*60, (3 + 24)*60]
->  {"22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"}
```

What I can't seem to manage is how to combine the two into a single definition of myTicks that avoids the need for the intermediate function f.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Look up `Function` in the documentation.

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific, please. I've tried this but it doesn't work.
    MyTicks2[min_, max_] :=
     Function[
       Module[{q, r},
        {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[#, 60];
        q = Mod[q, 24];
        q = IntegerString[q, 10, 2];
        r = IntegerString[r, 10, 2];
        StringJoin[q, ":", r]
        ]
       ] /@ FindDivisions[{min, max, 60}, 5]

Comment: You're missing the `&`.

Comment: In the Function documentation, basic examples In[2] doesn't have an &.

Comment: Did you look at the answer I posted, which has a complete example?  BTW the code you posted in the comment works fine.  I misread it originally.

Comment: Our comments were overlapping so I hadn't seen your answer, only the comment. Sorry for the confusion. I have marked your answer below as the answer.

Comment: Re your BTW comment: How bizarre. Just re-tried it from the comments above and it works. I must have screwed-up evaluating somehow. D'oh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
myTicks[min_, max_] :=
 Table[
  Module[{q, r},
   {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[x, 60];
   q = Mod[q, 24];
   q = IntegerString[q, 10, 2];
   r = IntegerString[r, 10, 2];
   StringJoin[q, ":", r]
   ],
  {x, FindDivisions[{min, max, 60}, 5]}
 ]
```

Another way:

```
myTicks[min_, max_] :=
 Module[{q, r},
    {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[#, 60];
    q = Mod[q, 24];
    q = IntegerString[q, 10, 2];
    r = IntegerString[r, 10, 2];
    StringJoin[q, ":", r]
  ] & /@ FindDivisions[{min, max, 60}, 5]
```

Look up [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

For the ultimate goal, you can use the internal function `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks `` to generate the date ticks:

```
ClearAll[hourminuteTicks]
hourminuteTicks = MapAt[Round[#/60] &, 
  System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[60 {#, #2}, #3, {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}], {All, 1}] &;
```

Example:

```
hourminuteTicks[22*60, (3 + 24)*60, 5]
```

> {{1320, "22:00"}, {1380, "23:00"}, {1440, "00:00"}, {1500, "01:00"}, {1560, "02:00"}, {1620, "03:00"}}

Take the last parts for the tick labels:

```
hourminuteTicks[22*60, (3 + 24)*60, 5][[All, 2]]
```

> {"22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact, completely unreadable way to achieve your goal:

```
myTicks[min_, max_] := (StringJoin @@ {IntegerString[Mod[#1, 24], 10, 2], 
         ":", IntegerString[#2, 10, 2]}) & @@ 
     QuotientRemainder[#, 60] & /@ FindDivisions[{min, max, 60}, 5];
```

For readability, I think intermediate functions can be helpful, and if an intermediate function is only needed inside some larger function, you can define it locally:

```
myTicks[min_, max_] := Module[{f},
  minToHHMM[x_] := Module[
    {h, m},
    {h, m} = {Mod[#1, 24], #2} & @@ QuotientRemainder[x, 60];
    {h, m} = IntegerString[#, 10, 2] & /@ {h, m};
    StringJoin[#1, ":", #2] & @@ {h, m}
    ];
  minToHHMM /@ FindDivisions[{min, max, 60}, 5]
  ]
```